# Irregular, non-linear grid with Python Imshow

Tags: python, imshow

I want to draw a 2D colormap with a non-linear stretched Y-axis. The values for the X-axis have the same spacing, but the Y-values have a variable spacing:

```
X=[1,2,3,4]
Y=[1,4,9,16]
```

In my matrix Z I have the brightness values (marked with a x):

```
z=[[x,x,x,x],[x,x,x,x],[x,x,x,x],[x,x,x,x]]
```

When I plot plt.imshow(z) I get evenly spaced "pixels":

```
x x x x 
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

But I need the y axis to be correct, so it should be like:

```
x x x x



x x x x

x x x x
x x x x
```

Is there a way to get such a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
import pylab as plt 
X=[1,2,3,4]
Y=[1,4,9,16]
z=[[x,x,x,x],[x,x,x,x],[x,x,x,x],[x,x,x,x]]
plt.contourf(X,Y,z,200)
```

?